# Autoredirect my page after filling the form

Tags: html, forms, redirect, form-submit

On my website (site1) i have created a form which is from (Site2) which is filled and submits automatically. However when it is submitted the action page is (site 2). I want to auto redirect to (site 1). HTML/Javascript i'm using... How can i do it

Comment: What about using AJAX and not redirecting at all and submit without refresh?

Comment: Use window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

Comment: window.location.replace my site 2 is a tottaly different site can it be done or does it need to be with the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PHP?
Site1:

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //*get the URL //*

<form action="site2" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="url" value="$url" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Site2:

```
$url=$_POST['url'];
//* do the form stuff //*
 header('location:'.$url.'');
```